# How do you use "useState" in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, react-native

How do I do something simple like this in Typescript?

```
const [text, setText] = useState("");
```

I'm getting a lot of errors, and I don't know how to fix them.

```
Parameter 'text' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)
Parameter 'setText' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)
'useState', which lacks return-type annotation, implicitly has an 'any' return type.ts(7010)
```

Comment: Do you have the types installed for react and react-native

Comment: `npm install --save-dev @types/react`.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I'm still new to Typescript. I tried running that command but Visual Code still gives me errors. Do I have to import react differently too?

Comment: Did you try `useState<string>("");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Jared Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3757232/jared-smith) suggested, you just need to install the `@types/react` package for example with

```
yarn add -D @types/react
```

or

```
npm install --save-dev @types/react
```

The usage is straightforward if your default value is of the same type as the actual value, but if you have multiple possible types than you have to specify the type yourself. F.e. if the state can be `null` or a string:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState<string | null>(null);
```

without the `<string | null>` type annotation you will get an error when you try to set a string as a value with

```
setValue("some string");
```